# Regex expressions working in HTML but not with JQuery's test function

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I'm using regex with HTML5's pattern function and its working as expected, but when I put that same function in a JQuery's .test function It doesn't work as expected. Any suggestions?

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#firstName').blur(function() {
                if(!(/[A-Za-z']{3,14}/.test($('#firstName').val()))){
                    alert("thats not a good first name");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <input type="text"id="firstName" placeholder="first name" pattern="[a-zA-Z']{3,14}" /> 

    <style type="text/css">input:valid{background:green;}input:invalid{background:red;}</style>
```

Comment: What's the problem ? What does it mean " doesn't work as expected" ?

Comment: it works fine for me in the test function

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: `/patt/.test()` is not a jQuery function. It's plain old JavaScript.

Comment: The way the html validation worked was as I expected, if you enter a string such as "jkh324kjh" or one over 14 characters the HTML and CSS marks the expression as correct but my javascript wont throw an alert. The problem had to do with how HTML and javascript interpret Regex expressions, HTML appears to interpret all expressions as strings and javascript needs to have the expression explicitly defined as a string by containing the expression in between a '^' and '$'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex instead

```
$('#firstName').blur(function () {
     if (!(/^([a-zA-Z]){3,14}$/.test($('#firstName').val()))) {
         alert("thats not a good first name");
     }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jLFa/1/)

Comment: This worked! It appears that HTML's validation function interpenetrates all Regex expressions as strings and Javascript's (thanks for the correction Mark) .test methods requires you to explicitly state that the expression is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [HTML5 Forms specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute):

> The compiled pattern regular expression, when matched against a string, must have its start anchored to the start of the string and its end anchored to the end of the string.
>
> Note: This implies that the regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the `pattern` attribute is matched against the entire value, not just any subset (somewhat as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end).

Also note that the constraint only applies **if the element's value is not the empty string**.

So if you want your javascript test to match the HTML pattern constraint you need to only perform the test when the field is not blank, and also make sure that the pattern matches the entire value or modify the pattern to include the `^` and `$` codes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually working. I changed the Javascript to this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#firstName').blur(function() {
                if((/[A-Za-z']{3,14}/.test($('#firstName').val()))){
                    console.log("Awesome name!");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Once you type valid input and then change focus on the element, console.log will trigger printing 'Awesome name!' to the console.

I think you need to evaluate on a different trigger than .blur.